# How can i crawl page but without fetching video/image content in nutch 2.1?

Tags: solr, lucene, web-crawler, nutch

I want to crawl a page and I need to take only the HTML itself, avoiding all images/videos etc... 
Is it possible to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check regex-urlfilter.txt file.

You can include the extensions of the file extensions which you dont want to index. e.g.

```
# skip image and other suffixes we can't yet parse
# for a more extensive coverage use the urlfilter-suffix plugin
-\.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip|ZIP|ppt|PPT|mpg|MPG|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|tgz|TGZ|mov|MOV|exe|EXE|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|js|JS)$
```

Comment: Yea, that's default configuration. I commented the code above in order to make sure that pictures are taken, and yes they are. Thank you for this.